# Date field change during Retrofit uploads

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, interceptor, okhttp

I am using Retrofit2 for upload SOAP request. Date automatically changes during the upload process in 10 out 1000 requests. I have investigated a lot and pin point the issue when I started logging the call with interceptor.

```
Log Printed before interceptor
fromTime:2018-10-13T13:22:00
isDeleted:false
name:Unknown visitor
reason:Unknown reason
toTime:2018-10-13T23:59:59
vrm:ABC


Log Printed in Interceptor.
FromTime:2018-10-20T11:59:00
Name:Unknown visitor
Reason:Unknown reason
ToTime:2018-10-13T23:59:59
Vrm:ABC
isDeleted:false
```

It can be seen fromTime:2018-10-13T13:22:00 changes to FromTime:2018-10-20T11:59:00.

Build request is as follow

```
public EnvelopeSender build() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new EnvelopInterceptor()).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().client(client)
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create(serializer))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(SynchronousCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(EnvelopeSender.class);
    }
```

Serialisation factory is as follow.

public class XMLSerializerFactory {

```
private Strategy strategy;
private DateFormat format;
private RegistryMatcher registryMatcher;

public Serializer getSerializer() {
    if (strategy == null && registryMatcher == null) {
        return new Persister();
    } else if (strategy == null) {
        return new Persister(registryMatcher);
    } else if (registryMatcher == null) {
        return new Persister(strategy);
    } else {
        return new Persister(strategy, registryMatcher);
    }
}

public XMLSerializerFactory withStrategy() {
    strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();
    return this;
}

public XMLSerializerFactory withDateFormat() {
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.UK);
    return this;
}

public XMLSerializerFactory withRegistryMatcher() {
    if (format == null)
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.UK);

    registryMatcher = new RegistryMatcher();
    registryMatcher.bind(Date.class, new DateFormatTransformer(format));
    return this;
}
```

}

```
public class DateFormatTransformer implements Transform<Date> {
    private DateFormat dateFormat;

    public DateFormatTransformer(DateFormat dateFormat) {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    @Override
    public Date read(String value) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.parse(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String write(Date value) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.format(value);
    }

}
```

Is it bug or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is in DateFormatTransformer ?

Comment: @stallianz I have added DateFormatTransformer for you in the question. It is a class for date time formatting.

Comment: sorry it doesn't have much information, can you send me actual call ?

Comment: @stallianz are you talking about SOAP envelop.

Comment: sorry, dates are too tricky in java, just wanted to know the call involved in getting "fromTime" from your example.